# C# BackgroundWorker blocking on Database call in DoWork handler

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am trying to follow the BackgroundWorker example listed here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkays279.aspx under the heading of "Returning Values from Multithreaded Procedures
"

I put a time consuming call to the database in the DoWork event handler of the BackgroundWorker. I expect that once I call BackgroundWorkerAsync(object) that this call will happen in the background and not block the rest of the application from executing. The problem is this does not happen. The whole application locks up and waits for the database call to return. Once it returns, the application is responsive again.

Here is my code

```
    //initialization in a method. 
    Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
    Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Retriever temp = (Retriever)e.Argument;
        e.Result = temp.RetrieveLongDBCallThatReturnsADataSet()  //App blocks until done. 
    }

   private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataSet result = (System.Data.DataSet)e.Result;

        //Do stuff with the DataSet. 
    }

    public void Retrieve(object arg1, object arg2, object arg3)
    {
        Retriever temp = new Retriever();

        InitializeBackgroundWorker(); //wire up events

        temp.Prop1 = arg1;
        temp.Prop2 = arg2;
        temp.Prop3 = arg3;

        Worker.RunWorkerAsync(temp);

        //Code that is expected to start executing, but instead blocks until temp.RetrieveLongDBCallThatReturnsADataSet() finishes. 
    }
```

Can anyone see what I am missing here? I did the same type of thing with a call to a WebService and that seems to be working fine.

Comment: Is the database accessed elsewhere? It is indeed the `DoWork` call that blocks the main UI? (Could this be a red-herring?)

Comment: Thanks for the response pst. I am not sure if I understand your question. Do you mean is there another process calling the DB while I am calling RunWorkerAsync? I can't see the DB being accessed elsewhere. Out of curiosity, I commented out that DB call in the Retriever class and replaced it with a  While(true) { }  After I did that, it the BackgroundWorker behaved as I expected it to. The application did not block, despite that infinite loop.

Comment: What are you doing in `RetrieveLongDBCallThatReturnsADataSet`? That's probably where the problem is...

Comment: `//Code that is expected to start executing`.  There should be no code there.  Move it to the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not happen unless:

You are waiting for the database result (or something which blocks UI thread) on the next lines after calling `DoWork` asynchronously.

Put a `Break Point` on the next line after calling `RunWorkerAsync` and you should get the flow immediately (or add that code to your question)

Comment: - Thank you for your response. Interesting... I placed a breakpoint right after the call to RunWorkAsync and I did go to the next line immediately. Here is where I am getting confused. The line after that next line is a Form.ShowDialog(). That form is no interaction/expectation with the DB results that I am expecting back, but that form blocks.  All that form is meant to do is scroll a progress bar while the results come back. The RunWorkerEventCompleted then closes that form.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in the code you are not showing. How are you updating the progress bar and what do you mean by "that form blocks"? Is it completely unresponsive / does it not update the progress bar / can you move it but it is not painting the controls?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. It turns out that it was code that was executing after the RunWorkerCompleted event fired off. The thing that threw me off was the form still showed on the screen while the code after the RunWorkerCompleted event ran. The code in the RunWorkerCompleted event, specifically closed the form.  The only thing I can think of is there was some repainting issue. Adding breakpoints further down the stream, showed me which code was blocking. I have moved that code to a BackgroundWorker and am now getting the results I was expecting. Thanks to all who responded.